# A Python 'append' list method bug?

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, methods, append

So, at computer science I've been killing some time and got myself onto this simple [problem](https://www.e-olymp.com/en/contests/13533/problems/130282). In short, you need to create an **n^2**-sized list, where you must input **n*n** numbers. Then you must find diagonal (since our list is kinda square-ish) numbers and add them (for the first and second diagonal). Better check the link for better explanation and examples included.

So, my issue is <s>WHY MY CODE IS NOT WORKING</s> why my code doesn't want to append 4 number when I have **n** to equal 2. Here's my code for the proper explanation:

```
n = int(input(''))
d = []

i = 0

while i < n * n: # a loop to input all the digits
    b = int(input(''))
    d.append(b) # here's where an error happens, even though I've input 4 times, PyCharm debug shows two integers in the list
    i += 1

sum1 = d.pop(0) # our first diagonal sum (undone)
sum2 = d.pop(n * n - n) # second diagonal sum (undone)

g = 1
x = n + 1 # addon for the .pop method
while g < n:
    sum1 += d.pop(x) # the trigger. code breaks because my list has only 2 integers inside, while x = 3 (when n = 2)
    x += 1 + n
    g += 1

# the other code is no-special
g = 1
p = n*n - 1
while g < n:
    sum2 += d.pop(p)
    p += n*n - 1
    g += 1

print(sum1, sum2)
```

I really look forward to resolve this issue. It's bothering me so much that I even wrote about it on a stackoverflow, ha-ha! Please don't mind that childish explanation in the beginning, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue. Entering ``2``, ``1``, ``2``, ``3``, ``4`` correctly results in ``d`` being ``[1, 2, 3, 4]`` and the loop ending. How do you get the debug output for the list?

Comment: Have you modified my code? If yes, please don't. Try do the same thing with a legacy one.
Edit: I'm using PyCharm debug. It's stated at one of the code's comment.

Comment: I have directly copied and run your code right before ``sum1 = d.pop(0)``.

Comment: Please consider running all the code. I've commented at the sum1 += d.pop(x) that it's the trigger of the issue.

Comment: By that line, you *already* ``pop``ed twice from the list - namely ``sum1`` and ``sum2``. With an initial content of 4 elements, it *must* have only 2 elements at that line. Are you aware that ``list.pop`` removes elements?

Comment: Holy shit you are right. How can I _copy_ the element from the list?

Comment: You probably want to use ``d[0]``, ``d[n * n - n]`` and so on.

Comment: Yeah I've done it already. Thanks. Pls write an **answer** to this question in order for other people to understand my and (probably) theirs mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: Use `d[i]` instead of `d.pop(i)`.

---

Python's `list.pop` method retrieves an item *and removes it* from the list:

> `s.pop([I])` retrieves the item at `i` and also removes it from `s`
>
> [Mutable Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)

This means your list has 4 items (given `n==2`) after the first loop, but only 2 after fetching `sum1` and `sum2`:

```
while i < n * n: # a loop to input all the digits
    b = int(input(''))
    d.append(b)
    i += 1
# length of d is 4

sum1 = d.pop(0)         # shorten d by 1
sum2 = d.pop(n * n - n) # shorten d by 1
# length if d is 2
```

To retrieve items without removing them from the list, use `s[i]` instead:

> `s[i]` `i`th item of `s`, origin 0
>
> [Common Sequence Operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

```
while i < n * n: # a loop to input all the digits
    b = int(input(''))
    d.append(b)
    i += 1
# length of d is 4

sum1 = d[0]
sum2 = d[n * n - n]
# length if d is still 4
```